# Most efficient way to create a Mat object using existing buffer in RGB format?

Tags: opencv

I have a bitmap in RGB format, i.e. 24bit per pixel. How can I create a Mat object so that I can minimize data copying while making sure that the order of the channel is treated correctly, given that default order in OpenCV is BGR

Comment: Please see my answer. If you have some processing in mind, please edit some code into your question, and I'll (try to) add a solution to my answer

Comment: "the order of the channels is treated corectly" ... openCV needs BGR ordering for functions like rendering, etc. So it depends on your algorithm whether it is ok to work with RGB color ordering or whether you have to convert to bgr first. If displaying is a problem, use Qt for example which needs RGB ordering to display in labels.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can use RGB order as usual, just remember to convert to correct color space when needed.

---

You can create a `Mat` header with no copies using:

```
int rows = ...
int cols = ...
uchar* rgb_buffer = ...

cv::Mat3b rgb_image(rows, cols, bgr_buffer);
```

None (or just a few) of the OpenCV functions assume that matrix data should be in BGR or RGB order. You can also operate on your data with your custom processing accounting for RGB order.

The fact that OpenCV images are in BGR order is mostly a matter of input / output (basically `imshow`, `imread`, `imwrite`, and the like).

You can always convert your image with `cvtColor(..., RGB2<whatever>)` in case you need to switch color space. This won't be a performance issue, since the data would be copied anyway.

Answer (score 0):

RGB buffer: 
int rows, int cols, uchar* input_RGB;

Mat buffer declaration: 
Mat image(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, input_RGB);

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html